# Using Blazor Server-side, is it possible to get file progress upload status from from the controller to the client on large files?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blazor

I want to be able to display an accurate progress of the file upload. Is there a way to communicate to the user the upload progress on large files being uploaded to Azure Storage?

What I have in place now updates the user on progress for multiple files by updating the progress bar after each individual file upload completed, but I don't want it to seem like the app is hanging on larger files when it's still working in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when using [BlazorFileReader](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader) this code will show the upload progress:

```
        foreach (var file in await fileReaderService
            .CreateReference(inputElement)
            .EnumerateFilesAsync())
        {
            var fileInfo = await file.ReadFileInfoAsync();

            var bufferSize = 4096;
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                var finalBuffer = new byte[fileInfo.Size];

                int count;
                int intCount = 0;
                while ((count = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, finalBuffer, intCount, count);
                    intCount = intCount + count;

                    int uploadPercentage = (int)((intCount * 100) / fileInfo.Size);
                    uploadMessage = "file upload " + uploadPercentage.ToString() + "%";
                    StateHasChanged();
                }

                uploadMessage = "The file is uploaded successfully";
                StateHasChanged();

            }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I used this in combination with PutBlockAsync on the back end, and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Blazor now supports this functionality out-of-the-box.
See here: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#upload-files-with-progress)