# Is there a way to show file uploading progress bar when uploading a file from a blazor WebAssembly (WASM) to a ASP.NET Core server (blazor hosted)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to inform users about the file upload progress of a file uploaded from the Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) client to the server project (Api).
P.S. I'm using NET 6.
Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#upload-files-with-progress

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for taking the time to post the docs link but as I've stated above I'm using Blazor WebAssembly aka WASM (Which resides on the client-side), if you switch to the Blazor WebAssembly tab you will notice that the "Upload files with progress" section disappears.

Comment: Are you just keeping the file in client-side local storage or does it then get sent somewhere?

Comment: sharing a couple of links : Tweet - https://twitter.com/geoffmbarlow/status/1521092174489739266 and their github repo https://github.com/agency8/BlazorFileUploadApp

Comment: You can try to refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617435/using-blazor-server-side-is-it-possible-to-get-file-progress-upload-status-from).

Comment: @MisterMagoo thank you that repo was really helpful! The Blazor community really needs more attention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/agency8/BlazorFileUploadApp Had everything I needed, just clone it and you can get on with your work...
Thanks to @MisterMagoo for sharing the link!